# Django: how to correctly delete database record to prevent primary key reuse?

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, primary-key

My expectation is that even after I delete a record with primary key `pk=k`, and later create a new record, this new record will get at least `pk=k+1`.

Environment: Python 2.7.8 + Django 1.6.5 + default sqlite3 enginie

My `/repeatId/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

`manage.py shell` interaction:

```
>>> from repeatId.models import Foo
>>> Foo.objects.all().count()
0
>>> Foo.objects.create(name='first')
<Foo: first>
>>> Foo.objects.all().count()
1
>>> foo = Foo.objects.all()[0]
>>> foo.id
1
>>> Foo.objects.get(id=1).delete()          <--- deleting initial obj with id=1
>>> Foo.objects.all().count()
0
>>> Foo.objects.create(name='second')
<Foo: second>
>>> Foo.objects.all().count()
1
>>> foo = Foo.objects.all()[0]
>>> foo.id                                  <--- expected to get id=2, but got id=1
1
```

Comment: Here's the Postgres side answer. Don't know about Django. Seems like you have to get pretty in depth to solve this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267050/postgresql-properly-change-id-of-table-row

Comment: Did you create the database using the version of Django you're currently running, or is it an old database?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Example in the post is produced in a newly created project and newly created app. The database of the project I'm working on was created under Django 1.5. So I think both case would fail.

Comment: @wlnirvana I can't quite figure out in [which version of Django the problem was fixed](https://github.com/django/django/commit/eade315da1c8372ac1dfcf1fd20ea87f454d71ac) but it looks like 1.7. It also mentions that the database needs to be migrated to fix the problem, since the code fix only affects new tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10164) in Django that [has been fixed](https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/eade315da1c8372ac1dfcf1fd20ea87f454d71ac) in version 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Create another model that forces only one record to store the last used pk for your foo model:

```
class FooPK(models.Model):
    last_used_foo_pk = models.IntegerField()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk == 1: #force only ONE record to ever be in the db
            super(FooPK, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Override Foo's save method to get the last used pk from FooPK, increment it, save it to both models

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        PKRecord = FooPK.objects.get(pk=1) #FooPK's only object pk will not change, you have forced only the first record to ever 
        new_pk = PKRecord.last_used_foo_pk + 1
        self.pk = new_pk
        super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        PKRecord.last_used_foo_pk = new_pk
        PKRecord.save()
```